# Am I lazy loading these properties?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

We're using Entity Framework 4.1 for our data acces and while building up objects and we started asking questions to ourselves 
about how chatty the application was going to be with the database. Now one item that we really started looking at is below:

```
public MasterPreAward()
{
   public int ID 
   public int MemberID 
   public int CycleID

   public virtual Cycle 
   public virtual Member 
   public virtual Status
   public virtual ICollection<DataTracking> DataTrackings
   public virtual ICollection<ReviewerAssignment> Reviewers
 }
```

The MasterPreAward is a generated entity from the database and has the navigation properites  of Cycle, Member, Status along with two collections for DataTrackings
Reviewers. What we were wondering was, how did Entity Framework load up the child objects based off of these items and bring back the data we use in the follow model?
As you can see, we're passing in MasterPreAward object and then accessing children properties which are loaded based on the MasterPreAward.

```
public ViewHeaderSummary(MasterPreAward masterPreAward)
{
   MasterPreAwardId = masterPreAward.ID;
   ClientId = masterPreAward.Cycle.Project.Program.ClientID;
   ApplicationId = masterPreAward.MemberID;
   ProgramId = masterPreAward.Cycle.Project.ProgramID;
   ProjectId = masterPreAward.Cycle.ProjectID;
   EventTypeId = masterPreAward.DataTrackings.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Finished==true
                      && x.EventTypeID==(int)FormEvents.Application).EventTypeID;
   CycleId = masterPreAward.CycleID;
   FormId = masterPreAward.Cycle.CycleForms.FirstOrDefault().FormID;
}
```

What we'd like to know, is this the best way to access these properties, or should be really be thinking doing this type of work in a different way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't seem to query for full entities but only for a bunch of scalar values. In my opinion this would be a good candidate for a projection which collects all the needed values in a single database roundtrip:

```
    var result = dbContext.MasterPreAwards
        .Where(m => m.ID == masterPreAward.ID)
        .Select(m => new
        {
            ClientId = m.Cycle.Project.Program.ClientID,
            ProgramId = m.Cycle.Project.ProgramID,
            ProjectId = m.Cycle.ProjectID,
            EventTypeId = m.DataTrackings.Where(d => d.Finished
                && x.EventTypeID==(int)FormEvents.Application)
                .Select(d => d.EventTypeID).FirstOrDefault(),
            FormId = m.Cycle.CycleForms.Select(c => c.FormID).FirstOrDefault()
        })
        .Single();

    MasterPreAwardId = masterPreAward.ID;
    ClientId = result.ClientID;
    ApplicationId = masterPreAward.MemberID;
    ProgramId = result.ProgramID;
    ProjectId = result.ProjectID;
    EventTypeId = result.EventTypeId;
    CycleId = masterPreAward.CycleID;
    FormId = result.FormID;
```

As you can see, you need the `DbContext` to run such a query.

Your original way to lazily load all related entities will lead to 5 database queries as far as I can see (for `Cycle`, `Project`, `Program`, `DataTrackings` and `CycleForms`). Worst of all are the queries for `DataTrackings.FirstOrDefault` and `CycleForms.FirstOrDefault` which will actually load the *full* collections first from the database into memory and then execute `FirstOrDefault` in memory on the loaded collections to return only one single element from which you then only use one single property.

(*Edit*: Query for `ApplicationId` and `CycleId` not necessary, Code changed.)

Comment: Thanks for the code example. This gives us a few more ideas to work with when we're building up a model or a repository.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the default settings would be to lazy load each nested collection independently, which could cause a lot of database traffic.

The best way to verify the generated SQL is to start a SQL profiler and confirm the number of queries.

You can force EF to eagerly load related entities by calling `.Include` method. See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/31/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-6-loading-related-entities.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the EF blog links. But I think what's we're really trying to do is avoid the eager loading of things and only pull what we need when we need it.